# I am able to pass the data from Spring boot controller to html page, but how do I access the data in Java Script?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

This is my Controller:

```
{@RequestMapping("/component")
public String component(Model model) {
    Class obj=new Class ();
    JSONObject data=obj.fetchData();
    model.addAttribute("message",  obj.getMessage());
    model.addAttribute("data", data);     
    return "component";
}}
```

I am able to print data in the view of component.html like this:

```
<p th:text=${data}></p>
```

but how do I get the data in Java Script? js_component.js is my source.

```
<script th:inline="javascript" src="js_component.js"></script>
```

I've already tried this code in js_component.js but it does not work.

```
/*<![CDATA[*/
var json=/*[[${data}]]*/ 'data';

var msg=/*[[${message}]]*/ 'message';

/*]]>*/
```

how do I get the data in Java Script?

Comment: Are you also processing `js_component.js` with Thymeleaf having the same context? Thing is, directive you're using seems to only work if that's indeed an inline script, which your script tag is not - it's a referenced script, not an inline one.

Comment: oh  okay, no it is not an inline script as it a big file. Is there any other way out?

Comment: Depends on what's a big file. Your inline script can declare global variables (on `window`, that is), and then the attached script could use those values from global scope. Alternatively, if a big file exports some kind of function for which those are parameters, you can import the file in inline script and call the function.

Comment: I've just found [there](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29130811/Thymeleaf-with-External-Javascript-files.html) that if you use `th:src` instead of plain `src`, then Thymeleaf will process the script file. Try that.

Comment: Alternatively, there are [template fragments](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#including-template-fragments) that could also work (also note section 8.2 about parameterized template fragments).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to return "js_component.js" at your controller.

```
@RequestMapping("/component")
public String component(Model model) {
    Class obj=new Class ();
    JSONObject data=obj.fetchData();
    model.addAttribute("message",  obj.getMessage());
    model.addAttribute("data", data);     
    return "js_component.js"; <==
}
```